# Modo de compatibilidad para Edge de una pagina creada con Html en Intranet

Tags: html, internet-explorer, edge

Tengo una página creada en Html con plantilla BootStrap v.3.3 para ejecutarla con Internet Explorer dentro de una intranet de la empresa.

El problema surge que desde que Windows deja de dar soporte a Internet Explorer e intento ejecutarla con el explorador Edge , me da varios problemas de compatibilidad.
No me abre directamente los archivos, sino que me muestra las rutas donde están y no los ejecuta directamente.
Os paso algunas capturas de pantalla para que veáis el problema.
La compatibilidad con el IE está activada en el explorador Edge.

Como veis en la imagen Ejemplo1 , me abre en el explorador una pestaña donde me indica la ruta y los archivos que contiene, cuando lo que debería hacer es como sale en la imagen Ejemplo 2, abrir el cuadro de dialogo con la ruta seleccionada.

Me gustaría saber si tengo que añadir algo a mi código Html para que funcione.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

[image: Ejemplo1]

[image: Ejemplo2]

Comment: La imagen dos es el explorador de archivos... nada que ver con html este problema...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No se entiende el problema, debes intenar explicarlo mejor. Pero yo acabo de hacer una prueba en EDGE y al abrir un excel de forma local (`file:///c:/etc/unexcel.xlsx`) no tengo problema. Me aparece un mensaje de abrir o guardar, le doy a abrir y se abre correctamente

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas, a ver si me puedo explicar un poco mejor. Cuando en principio en Iexplorer yo hacía click en en un link como en el que muestro en la imagen , lo  que hacía es abrir el cuadro de diálogo de windows, ahora en Microsoft Edge, cuando hago click en el mismo link, lo que hace es abrirme otra pestaña de internet con la ruta y los archivos que contiene, en vez del cuadro de diálogo.